# Solve not working

Tags: equation-solving

I'm trying to solve the following system of equations for `ahat0, ahat1, ahat2` using the `Solve` function.

I know (algebraically) that a system exists, but *Mathematica* isn't converging. I've triple checked my syntax, and I'm unsure what's going on (i.e. why *Mathematica* won't give me a solution). Attaching the equations and the code here to explain what I mean.

```
Solve[{ahat0 + ahat1 t + ahat2 t^2 - m bar == 0,
  ahat0 t + ahat1 t^2 + ahat2 t^3 - mtbar == 0,
  ahat0 t^2 + ahat1 t^3 + ahat2 t^4 - mt2bar == 0},
  {ahat0, ahat1, ahat2}]
```

[image]

Comment: In a new fresh notebook and replacing `Solve` with `Reduce` returns an answer in a fraction of a second. Then `Simplify` that result to make it even smaller.

Comment: What does the bar over t, t^2 etc. mean? It probably means that $\overline{t^2}$ does not equal $\overline{t}^2$

Comment: Based on the way you wrote all the other variable names in your little block of code, and thank you profusely for including that block of code, that is so helpful, you might have wanted `mbar` as a single variable with no space between `m` and `bar` rather than `m bar` with a space in the middle which makes that into two variables multiplied together. If there is that space or not then `Solve` returns `{}` indicating that it could find no solution. `Reduce` on the other hand finds one kind of solution with the space present and a different solution with the space removed. Hopefully this helps

Comment: @Bill - Oddly, adding the option `Method -> Reduce` to `Solve` does not return a result even though the documentation for `Solve` states "With Method -> Reduce, Solve uses Reduce to find the complete solution set"

Comment: @CarlWoll the bar over (t_bar)^2 means an average (t_bar) was squared,  (t^2)bar means that t was squared, then the average was taken. you are correct that the two terms are not equal.

Comment: @Bill that's for catching the space! the only thing is that I'm having a hard time understanding the output from reduce.

Comment: That’s why your Solve didn’t work. Use t1bar, t2bar, etc instead and you will get a solution

Comment: @CarlWoll this is super helpful, these are all coefficients, they're not actually squared (cubed, etc) terms. thank you SO SO SO much - really resisted using MATLAB for this one :-)

Comment: To understand the output of Reduce you need to very carefully watch how  things are grouped together with ( and )  and remember that && means "and" and "||" means " or". Hopefully that will get you started. If you have a puzzling result that you can't figure out then please post it as carefully as you can and someone can try to explain it.